# How get response url in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I send a request from service A to service B. How can I get the URL address of service A in service B? For example, www.a.ru in www.b.ru. I need to get in B www.a.ru

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean **"how get request IP address?"**.

You make request from the server A to the server B. On the server B side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/server-B", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr()); // here will be server A IP address
        return "Success";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

send URL address of service A at body of request